# How to pass in options to a Dialog when using TestFlow - Azure botframework v4 - C# - Unit Tests

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, xunit

Using Azure Bot framework v4 - C# ... xunit...

I have the following unit test for testing a Component Dialog that in turn uses an AdaptiveDialog.

As part of unit testing the dialog, I want to pass in options to the dialog - the options that get passed to the OnBeginDialogAsync overload of the Dialog class.

Any thoughts on how we can pass myDialogOptions as the options to the dialog?

Thank you
Regards
Athadu

```
    public class ConfirmationDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        public class Options
        {
            public string PromptTemplate { get; set; }
        }

        public ConfirmationDialog()
            : base("test")
        {
            
        }

        protected override Task<DialogTurnResult> OnBeginDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            //
            // Avoiding using BotState here.  Instead ... use options...
            //    do something based on passed in options 
            //
        }
    }

        [Fact]
        public async Task TestMyComponentDialogThatUsesAdaptiveDialog()
        {
            //Arrange
            Setup();
            TestAdapter = (TestAdapter)new TestAdapter("my")
                                .UseStorage(memoryStorage)
                                .UseBotState(UserState, ConversationState)
                                .Use(Middlewares[0]);
            var dialogState = ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("dialogState");

            var dialogToTest = new ConfirmationDialog();
            var dialogManager = new DialogManager(dialogToTest);

            var myDialogOptions = new MyOptions { Name = "Jon Doe" };

            await new TestFlow(TestAdapter, async (turnContext, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                <<<<<<  How to pass in Dialog Options myDialogOptions to the dialog - need to access it within OnBeginDialogAsync >>>>>
                <<<<<<  of Dialog class override method OnBeginDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)   >>>>>

                var result = await dialogManager.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            })
            //Act
             .SendConversationUpdate()
            //Assert
             .AssertReply(activity =>
                 {
                     var resolvedActivity = activity.AsMessageActivity();
                     resolvedActivity.Text.Should().StartWith("Some Text");
                 }, null, 2100)
             .StartTestAsync();
        }
```

Comment: There aren't any adaptive dialogs in your code sample, so what do you mean when you say the component dialog "uses" an adaptive dialog? Is that a sub-dialog that we're not seeing? You don't appear to add any dialogs in the component dialog's constructor. Also, are you able to call BeginDialogAsync explicitly or do you need to use DialogManager for some reason?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @Kyle 

We abandoned my approach ... not relying on dialog options.In any case, my code does have an adaptive dialog.  I missed putting in the sample code.

The alternate approach we are using is ConversationState to pass in parameters to the child dialog.

I am still looking at the dialog options approach for may be later use.

Thank you 
Athadu

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/DialogManager.cs#L364-L390) that dialog managers don't pass any options to their root dialogs:

> ```
> private async Task<DialogTurnResult> HandleBotOnTurnAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> {
>     DialogTurnResult turnResult;
>
>     // the bot is running as a root bot. 
>     if (dc.ActiveDialog == null)
>     {
>         // start root dialog
>         turnResult = await dc.BeginDialogAsync(_rootDialogId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         // Continue execution
>         // - This will apply any queued up interruptions and execute the current/next step(s).
>         turnResult = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
>
>         if (turnResult.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty)
>         {
>             // restart root dialog
>             turnResult = await dc.BeginDialogAsync(_rootDialogId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
>         }
>     }
>
>     await SendStateSnapshotTraceAsync(dc, "Bot State", cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
>
>     return turnResult;
> }
> ```

If you want to pass options to `BeginDialogAsync` then you should call that or `PromptAsync` yourself.